# create multiple selectboxes from json and with different levels

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I have a JSON string from which I want to create multiple selectboxes. The problem however is that one value is somewhere deeper hidden in the JSON file. Further the json file is created dynamically so everything should work dynamically.

So my question is how to create the selectboxes and how do I get the value which lays deeper in the JSON file into the same select box?

JSON

```
{

    "product": {
options": {

    "58395": {
        "id": 58395,
        "title": "Size",
        "values": {
            "220544": {
                "id": 220544,
                "title": "36",
                "active": true
            },
            "220545": {
                "id": 220545,
                "title": "37",
                "active": false
            },
            "220546": {
                "id": 220546,
                "title": "38",
                "active": false
            },
            "220547": {
                "id": 220547,
                "title": "39",
                "active": false
            }
        }
    },
    "61295": {
        "id": 61295,
        "title": "Color",
        "values": {
            "231911": {
                "id": 231911,
                "title": "Zwart",
                "active": true
            },
            "231912": {
                "id": 231912,
                "title": "Bruin",
                "active": false
            },
            "231913": {
                "id": 231913,
                "title": "Rood",
                "active": false
            }
        }
    },
    "61296": {
        "id": 61296,
        "title": "Fabric",
        "values": {
            "231914": {
                "id": 231914,
                "title": "1",
                "active": true
            },
            "231915": {
                "id": 231915,
                "title": "2",
                "active": false
            },
            "231916": {
                "id": 231916,
                "title": "3",
                "active": false
            }
        }
    }

}, // etc....
```

So what I try to do is create 3 selectboxes -> Size, color and fabric. Inside these selectboxes have to come the `value title`. So you get something like:

```
<option value=' + option.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>
```

So what I tried was this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
  $.getJSON(url, function (data){
    var $selectOptions = $('<select />');
    $.each(data.product.options, function (index, option){
        var ids = "";
        $.each(options.values, function (i, v) { ids += " " + v.id; });
        $selectOptions.append('<option value=' + option.id + '>' +option.value.title + ids + '</option>');
    }); //etcetc...
```

This generates just one selectbox with with all option names inside it. Instead of the value titles.

Can anybody help me with this. I really can't figure this one out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand... you want to create 3 select boxed one for each option you have with the values as options...

why you dont try this

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data){
     var $selectOptions = $('<div />');
     $.each(data.product.options, function (index, option){
        var select = $('<select />');
        $.each(option.values, function (i, value) { 
            select.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
        });
        $selectOptions.append('<label>' + option.value + '</label>');
        $selectOptions.append(select);
}); //etcetc...
```

I hope this will help you maybe to modified at your taste...

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you want this

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data){
     var $selectOptions = $('<div />');
     $.each(data.product.options, function (index, option){
        var select = $('<select />');
        $.each(option.values, function (i, value) { 
            select.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + option.title + ': ' + value.title + '</option>');
        });
        $selectOptions.append(select);
}); //etcetc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build one select for each member of the options array object. Replace your $.getJSON() callback with something like this:

```
var products_el = $('#products');
$.getJSON(url, function(product_data) {
    for(var product_id in product_data) {
        var product = product_data[product_id];
        var product_el = $('<div class="product"><h3>' + product_id + '</h3></div>').appendTo(products_el);
        product_el.attr('id',product_id);
        for(var select_id in product.options) {
            var select = product.options[select_id];
            var select_wrap = $('<p><b>' + select.title + ' </b></p>').appendTo(product_el);
            var select_el = $('<select name="' + select_id + '" id="select_' + select_id + '"/>').appendTo(select_wrap);
            for(var option_id in select.values) {
                var option = select.values[option_id];
                var option_el = $('<option value="' + option.id + '" ' + (option.active ? 'selected' : '') + '>' + option.title + '</option>').appendTo(select_el);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hr4tn3k/1/

Comment: Thx but I need to use getJSON in order to get the json file.

Comment: Check the edit... you can replace the second argument with that function, either as an anonymous function (in the edit) or passed by variable as in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Ok thx but accepted answer is shorter and more readable for me :) Thx anyway